# Xamarin Studio: Property get lost after pushing viewcontroller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, storyboard

```
MyViewController vc = AppDelegate.storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("MyViewController") as MyViewController;

vc.SomeProperty = someValue;
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (vc, true);
```

I don't know why my property value get lost on ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear,... the property is null. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because you're overwriting it somewhere or `someValue` is already null? Hard to say without any further code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late response, but I was on the phone. :/
I found it out:
The problem was, that I used the push method in the storyboard and also in the ViewController with ...touchUpInside += Handle.... 
Now I have overridden the PrepareForSegue method and used the DestinationViewController to change my Property. Now it works.
Thats my first project with storyboard, so some experience is missing. :)

But thanks anyway for help.